# Keep class methods but obfuscate packages in proguard

Tags: obfuscation, proguard

> com.company.package1.CLASS 
>    - public void MethodA (); 
>    - public void MethodB ();
>    - public void MethodC ();

The CLASS has 3 public methods and I need to keep them, but the package could be remove. I.e. the expected result could be

> a.b.c.CLASS or a.b.c.D(alternative, the class name is obfuscated too) 
>    - public void MethodA ();
>    - public void MethodB ();
>    - public void MethodC ();

I wrote some scripts but how to extends them in order to fulfill my requirement.

> ```
>     -keep class 
>         com.company.package1.CLASS {
>         public <methods>;
>     }
>
>     -repackageclasses ''
>     -allowaccessmodification
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-keepclassmembers` instead of `-keep` -- cfr. ProGuard manual > Usage > [Overview of -keep options](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepoverview).

Answer (score 5):

use keep with allowobfuscation modifier, like below

`-keep,allowobfuscation class xx`

Comment: This will keep the class and its members (even if unused) , yet just change their names ? If not, how do to it? I want to do it for all classes in some package name.